# an unknown error while installing ADT versoin 22.0.5

Tags: android, adt

I **DO** need your help.I followed this steps for installing ADT 22.0.5 . this step is declared in developer.android.google.com for installing ADT:

> 1.Download the ADT Plugin zip file (do not unpack it)
>
> 2.Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
>
> 3.Click Add, in the top-right corner.
>
> 4.In the Add Repository dialog, click Archive.
>
> 5.Select the downloaded ADT-22.0.5.zip file and click OK.
>
> 6.Enter "ADT Plugin" for the name and click OK.
>
> 7.In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
>
> 8.In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
>
> 9.Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
>
> 10.If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
>
> When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

BUT after step 2, I had this error :

> An error occurred while installing the items
>   session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=[R]com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms 21.1.0.2013-2-6-0-46 --> [R]com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759, action=).
>   Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759.

**Please help me ! I searched a lot but I couldn't find anything about this error ! **

Comment: This is the method for installing ADT when you have problems with the recommended method, which is far simpler. Have you tried following the first set of instructions for installing ADT at [Installing the Eclipse Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)?

Comment: yes I tried that method , but I had problem with that method too. actually I am using this (zip archive) method as an alternative method !

Comment: Have you tried completely removing Eclipse from your computer and starting over?

Comment: No . you mean I remove this Eclipse and download again ? or just change its directory ?

Comment: I would try removing it and downloading again.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to lower version of the Eclipse.

In Eclipse Help -> Install New Software

Add this Url https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

For more details Follow http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and was not able to overcome it without downloading ADT again and installing/extracting it again.  I think that will be the fastest coarse of action for anyone experiencing this. Fortunately, the new ADT has the updates already applied.

In my case, I extracted ADT on top of my existing install. This kept my existing non-standard extensions in place, which was nice. There could be adverse side effects to doing this though. So, I would only recommend it if you are prepared to identify and deal with any oddities that come up.

Comment: I solved my problem by deleting eclipse and downloading new version from developer site!! It wasn't best way, but worked!!!